# Связанный dropdown и выключение child поля на время отправки запроса

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2

Делаю связанный `dropdown`.
При выборе категории в `parent dropdown` отображаются подкатегории в `child dropdown`.
При загрузке страницы `child` выключен и когда в него загружаются данные - он включается.
Мне нужно выключать `child` на время выполнения повторного запроса, когда в нем уже есть данные.

Как можно это сделать в случае использования `$.get()` ?
Или нужно в таком случае использовать полноценный `$.ajax()` и перед отправкой, к примеру, выключать `child dropdown`?

```
echo $form->field($model, 'category_id')->dropDownList($catList,
[
    'prompt'   => '- Choose a Category -',
    'onchange' => '
                    $.get( "' . Url::toRoute('site/get-subcat?id=') . '", { id: $(this).val() } )
                        .done(function( data ) {
                            $( "#' . Html::getInputId($model, 'sub_cat_id') . '" ).html( data ).attr("disabled", false);
                        }
                    );
                '
]);
```